# How do I get my jQuery variable to display after the page refreshes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a variable in my jQuery called `storedDealer` that I want to be filled with the option text when a drop-down item is selected:

```js
var storedDealer = '';

$(document).ready(function () {
    let dealerId = @Model.DealerID;
    if (0 < dealerId.length) {
        $("#DealerID option[value='dealerId'']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        $('#dealershipName').val(storedDealer);
    }
    $('#DealerID').on("change", function () {
        storedDealer = this.value;
    });
});

function getDealers(el) {
    $.get("@Url.Action("GetDealers", "Admin")?region=" + $(el).val(), function (res) {
        var markup = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            markup += '<option value='+res[i].Value+'>'+res[i].Text+"</option>"
        }
        $('#DealerID').prop('disabled', false);
        $("#DealerID").html(markup).show();
    });
}
```

My HTML has a little bit of C# Razor code that is the only place the `DealerID` is defined. I have added the `<var id="dealershipName">` item:

```html
<tr>
    <td align="right">Dealership:</td>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DealerID, new List<SelectListItem>())</td>
    <td><var id="dealershipName" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

I would not have thought the Razor variables would be visible by jQuery, but they somehow seem to work.

But when the search is submitted, the page refreshes. Now the drop-down list is reset and the `<var>` field is blank.

That `<var>` field is what I added, and I am trying to get to work.

How can I get the value to stay after the form reloads?

Comment: you've declare `storedDealer` with `const` so it can't be changed.

Comment: @MattEllen - really!? My limited understanding of javascript could be the issue here. Should I use `var storedDealer` instead?

Comment: @jp2code i think your best option would be to save the variable in local storage and then read it again once the page refreshed. Or maybe add it to the url (as a query string?) which you can also read once the page refreshes...

Comment: Check browser for errors - if it was caused by `const` you would get `Assignment to constant variable.` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try to use `Session`,here is a demo for .net6.Each time the slected value is changed,change `storedDealer`  and the session data.And when you refresh the page,if the session data is not null,`storedDealer`  will be set with the session data:

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

actions:

```
 public IActionResult Test(){
        return View();
    }
    public void SetSession(string storedDealer) {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("storedDealer", storedDealer);
        }
```

Test view:

```
var storedDealer = "";

$(document).ready(function () {
    let dealerId = @Model.DealerID;
    if (0 < dealerId.length) {
        $("#DealerID option[value='dealerId'']").attr('selected', 'selected');
        if(storedDealer==""&&"@(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Session.GetString("storedDealer")))"!=True)
        {
            storedDealer = "@Context.Session.GetString("storedDealer")";
        }
        $('#dealershipName').val(storedDealer);
    }
    $('#DealerID').on("change", function () {
        storedDealer = this.value;
        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "SetSession",
                            data: {storedDealer:$("#IdSelectIdEmpleado").val()},
                        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That is much more involved than I would have expected. This company is still running .NET Framework 4.5.2. Before I change multiple files in the project, I should ask: Do you know if this approach is feasible in v 4.5.2?

Comment: If you are in .net framework,you can try to refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8).